# Proper way to handle file writes in separate threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, executorservice

I am looking to write to files multiple times (100k+) and the writes will happen over a flaky network. So to do this, I am considering using the Java `ExecutorService` to help generate threads, but I'm not quite sure which combination of settings will properly make the following happen:

1. Only allow 1 write to happen at a time (order matters of course)
2. Allow the write ample time to conduct each write (say 5 second) at which point just bail
3. If the writing is slow, have the Executor collect the writes in a queue and wait.
4. Don't allow the overall program to exit until the thread queue is empty.
5. Separate the threads by writers. I.e., if the same exact writer comes in this function, put it in its own queue. If a different writer pointer comes in, give that its own queue (no need to put separate writers in the same queue).

I believe this can be done with a combination of the executor features along with the `.wait()` and `.notify()` command on the main program's object. However, I am just not really sure how to precisely work the executor API to get this done.

Here is what I got:

```
private void writeToFileInSeperateThread(final PrintWriter writer, final String text) {
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  try {
    executor.submit(new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        writer.println(text);
      }
    })).get(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  executor.shutdown();
}
```

That method will get called 100k+ times during a single process, so I'm not sure if I should be creating a new `ExcutorService` instance each time, or utilizing the same one? (In my attempts to utilize the same one, I kept getting exceptions which I believe were related to the `.newSingleThreadExecutor()` directive.

Would like to stay Java 5 compliant but Java 6 is okay. Running on Windows XP/7.

Update:
This seems to have done the trick in initial testing:

```
  private class WriterStringPair {
    public final PrintWriter writer;
    public final String text;

    public WriterStringPair(PrintWriter writer, String text) {
      this.writer = writer;
      this.text = text;
    }
  }

  private void writeTextInSeperateThread(Writer writer, String text) {
    try {
      textQueue.offer(new WriterStringPair(writer, text), 300L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      errOut.println(e);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  final BlockingQueue<WriterStringPair> textQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<WriterStringPair>(500);

  private void setWritingThread() {
    new Thread((new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        WriterStringPair q;
        while (!shutdown && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          try {
            q = textQueue.poll(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (q != null) {
              q.writer.write(q.text + "\n");
              q.writer.flush();
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    })).start();
  }
```

Comment: You say file writes over a network.  You talking about NFS or something?  You might consider using sftp or better protocols which may do better over the "flaky" network.

Comment: NFS is what I am stuck with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more details about your writing files over a "flaky" network and what the means, it's hard for us to give specifics.  But here are some things to think about.

I would figure out what number of concurrent writers gives you the best performance here -- or the most reliable output on the destination.  Then you should start a fixed number of these writers, each consuming from a shared `BlockingQueue` (or one queue per writer if it matters).  You should quickly exceed your IO or network bandwidth so starting at 5 or so writers and going up or down as necessary should work.

```
public void run() {
   writer.println(text);
}
```

Yeah, you don't want to do this sort of thing in terms of a job per line.  It would be  better to put the `String text` into a `BlockingQueue<String>` and then have your writer `Runnable` classes running in an `ExecutorService` dequeueing from that queue and only stopping when the queue is empty or a `shutdown` boolean is set.

As Peter mentions, you need to be careful about filling memory with your queued text strings.  If the input text is large, you should set a limit on your `BlockingQueue` to a couple of hundred or so.

> I'm not sure if I should be creating a new `ExecutorService` instance each time, or utilizing the same one?

Certainly you should have a single service and *not* create one over and over.

> I believe this can be done with a combination of the executor features along with the .wait() and .notify() command on the main program's object.

You shouldn't need to use wait and notify if you write this correctly.  I'd have a `volatile boolean shutdown = false` that all of your writers watch.  Each of them dequeues from the text queue using looking at the shutdown.  Something like:

```
while (!shutdown && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupgted()) {
    String text = textQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (text != null) {
        // write the text
    }
}
```

If the write fail or something you can just retry it or whatever is necessary.

Comment: Ah that is an interesting idea -- Add the writers and texts to a blockingqueue who is executing its thing in its own thread. I will look into that!

Comment: So the writers would be in the `ExecutorService` @EricS and the texts would be in the shared `BlockingQueue`.  FYI.

Comment: what is a good limit on the size of the BlockingQueue? I am putting in 500. But would INT_MAX be okay? (Also I abandoned the use of Executor Server and opted for a simple Thread -- I assume that's fine).

Comment: Single thread is fine, sure.  I would not do `INT_MAX` because I assume that the thread that is filling the blocking queue is going to be running faster than the writer.  You then will load all of your input into memory.  That might be ok however @EricS.

Comment: Actually, no point in doing that. I researched BlockingQueue more and say that once you hit capacity, it will wait on its own. I guess the only thing to watch out for is a blocking queue that waits forever... EDIT: Oh hey, BlockingQueue has a .offer() method which handles long time delays!

Comment: Right it will wait until the writers dequeue.  That was my point.  You don't want to set it to be Integer.MAX_VALUE @EricS.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues

- println doesn't tell you if there has been an IOException, so if you want some protection from errors, this won't help.
- starting an ExecutorService for each line is very slow, much slower than submitting tasks.
- creating lots of tasks will not only be very slow, but could use up all your memory if it it.
- you submit Runnable, not Threads to an ExecutorService
- shutdown doesn't stop a thread if for example it is blocking on a write. This could lead to many threads left lying around trying to write all at the same time.

I suggest persisting the data to a local system like JMS or a database or files (e.g. Java-Chronicle) and have a separate process copy the data to the NFS when it's available.

That is assuming you can't fix the NFS so it's not flaky.

Comment: Hmm, so println won't throw IOExceptions even if there is a Disk I/O error?

Comment: @EricS It never throws an exception of any kind.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to .write(text + "\n") now.

Comment: @EricS If you are worried about performance, I wouldn't do a string concatenation, do two write() instead assuming your Writer is buffered.

Comment: I recall reading that StringBuffer is called in the background automatically when Strings use + concat techniques, at least when not in loops. So either way, stream buffer or string buffer, that is going on in the background.

Comment: Java 5.0 and later using StringBuilder. If you use two write() calls there is no StringBuilder or resulting String created.